# How can I get the User ID from my database -- rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I'm using Devise for Authentication on rails. 
Now I'm building an API in which there is an instance where I need to return the user's id which has the email which is sent as a parameter. 
Simply, User enters email and gets his USER ID as the result. I'm using GRAPE for API.

```
@user = User.where(:email => params[:email])
@user.id
```

However, this returns an error.

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `id' for #<User::ActiveRecord_Relation:....
```

Now I want to know how can I retrieve a user's ID having his email ?

Appreciate any help.

Thanks.

P.S. Don't want to use current_user as this is something done using API Keys and not DEVISE SESSIONS.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Calling `User.where` will always return an ActiveRecord::Relation - a list of User records, even if the list contains one (or zero!) records.

If you expect to only get one record, you can use `User.find_by`, eg. `User.find_by(email: params[:email])`. This will return you either a User record, which you can call `id` on, or `nil` if no User matches.

Comment: Thanks! It works! Still didn't figure how I missed this simple basic point .. Haha..